# html vertical alignment and align center in h2 tag

Tags: html

Can you let me know is there any mistakes in the code below? It neither align the  text in center nor in middle(vertical).

```
<td> <h2 style = "align:center; vertical-align:middle;">TEXT</h2></td>
```

Comment: can you please add the full division, in which you are trying to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To center the element on the page (horizontally AND vertically) you might want to use margins. There are different ways of doing this; this is just one of them. The margins will be half the size of the container element. Example:

```
<td style="width:100%; height:100%;"> 
 <h2 style="position:absolute;top: 50%; left: 50%;">TEXT</h2> 
</td>
```

**NOTE**: The vertical-align property works with images, not with text which is why you need to find other solutions to center your text on a page or within an element. One way is this; margins.

A **drawback** of this approach is the fact that the center of the element is not taken to center it on the page; it is pushed to the middle from the borders of the element so to speak. This means that with larger elements the top left corner will be in the center of the page instead of the center point of the element. You can fix this by using negative margins given the size of the element.  You need to know the size of the element you are centering. Example:

If the element to be centered (class .centered) is 200px by 100px, the **CSS** to center it from the **center of the element** would look like this:

```
.centered { 
 position: fixed;  
 top: 50%;  
 left: 50%;  
 margin-top: -50px;  
 margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The style you are looking for is actually called `text-align`, not `align`. Moreover, the `vertical-align` style won't help you here, if what you want is to vertically align the header within its cell. Try the following:

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">TEXT</h2>
</td>
```